# How to include custom JS to admin create new product in magento 2

Tags: product, module, javascript, adminform, magento-2.2.5

I want to include custom JavaScript to `create new product form`.

**I already try with below way**

1. Using XML way.

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/index_index_add.xml

```
<head>
    <link src="Namespace_modulename::js/website_validation.js"/>
</head>
```

2. Using `require-config.js` way

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/require-config.js

```
var config = {
   'paths': {
       websitevalidation: 'Namespace_Modulename/js/website_validation'
   }
};
```

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/web/js/website_validation.js

```
require(['jquery','websitevalidation'],function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        alert('innn');

    });
});
```

What i missing or wrong in above code.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your xml file name in 1 way (Using xml way)

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/index_index_add.xml

Change layout xml file name to

> `catalog_product_new.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Use...

`app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_new.xml`